# Why was my question closed as "too story-based"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

[How can unconditional physician-assisted suicide be approved for anyone 18 or older?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/160800/69651) was closed wrongly.

> "You are asking questions about a story set in a world instead of about building a world. For more information, see Why is my question "Too Story Based" and how do I get it opened?." – Halfthawed, Renan, Frostfyre, puppetsock, Separatrix

How can I be "asking questions about a story set in a world" when unconditional physician-assisted suicide for anyone 18 or older doesn't exist, and probably won't for a while? I want to build this world.

First, these two comments are dead (pun intended) wrong, but got upvoted.

> [Alabama has never officially considered adopting a death with dignity law. The state has, in fact, taken an opposing path. In 2017, the Alabama legislature passed a law declaring it a crime for a health care provider to knowingly prescribe medication intended to cause death.](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/death-with-dignity-alabama.html)
>
> [Beginning on August 1, 2017, assisted suicide will be a Class C felony, punishable by up to 10 years in prison.  Prior to then, assisted suicide was dealt with under common law.](http://www.patientsrightscouncil.org/site/alabama/)

Second, I asked about unconditional PAS. Dignitas doesn't do that.

> [1.7. Examination carried out by DIGNITAS](http://www.dignitas.ch/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=23&Itemid=84&lang=en)
>
> After a request has been received, DIGNITAS staff members will examine it for completeness. They will also give consideration to the question of whether the applicant can be given any immediate recommendations for possible alternatives with the hope of being able to continue life under better conditions.

[image]

Comment: Would you like to include an argument in this question as to why you think that the question is not too story-based? The comments would seem to be not relevant to your point.

Comment: @WeareMonica. done

Answer (score 4):

The rationales are obvious:  first, your question is asking for a methodology.  This is the nature of how-is-it-done questions, in this case, within the context of a fictional story.

Second, you yourself stipulate that this is a matter of plot structuring when you state quite clearly that this is a question of fictional narrative.

Because of these facts, the answer is simply a matter of narrativity: if you need this to be so for the purposes of your story, then **it is so**.  We don't deal with these kinds of questions because there is no worldbuilding involved.  You would need to edit your query in order to remove the narrative aspects and in stead focus on matters of culture & history, morality & ethics, government & politics. ***THAT*** is worldbuilding.